# VideoView Online Buffer android Rotate Handle

Tags: java, android, video-streaming, android-videoview, screen-orientation

show online video my problem is : 
when **rotate** screen Video again from the beginning to **buffer** video

```
  @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        outState.putInt("POSITION", myVideo.getCurrentPosition());
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        myVideo.seekTo(savedInstanceState.getInt("POSITION"));
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help you

You have to write `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` in **AndroidManifest.java** file

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"/>
```

Comment: but not work '  Display display = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
        final int orientation = display.getRotation();'